# boost causes "too few template arguments for class template 'vector'"

Tags: c++, boost

I have this simple program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/unordered_map.hpp"

int main() {
    std::vector<unsigned char> v;
    v.push_back('a');
    std::cout << "Hello " << v[0] << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile with

```
clang++ -I/usr/local/include -std=c++11 vec.cpp
```

I get this error:

```
vec.cpp:6:10: error: too few template arguments for class template 'vector'
    std::vector<unsigned char> v;
         ^
/usr/local/include/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp:86:47: note: template is declared here
    template <class T, class Allocator> class vector;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~       ^
```

Removing the "include boost" line from the c++ file removes the error.  I am on OS X 10.10.3, and I installed boost using homebrew, if that makes any difference.  From what I can tell it seems like boost is overwriting the vector template to something nonstandard?  What can I do about this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with gcc/stdlibc++ and clang/libc++ on Linux.

Comment: Which version of boost is that? Are you _sure_ you include those in the order specified (`<vector>` before /usr/local/include/boost/detail/container_fwd.hpp)? Maybe try with `<boost/unordered_map.hpp>` for good measure too

Comment: works fine on my system, same OS X 10.10.3, boost 1.57.0

Comment: How did you install boost?  I'm thinking it may be a problem with homebrew, it says version 1.57.0 but maybe there is a problem with the install.

Comment: I agree with emeraldemon. There seems to be a problem with the boost installation. You installed boost on OS X, but the critical code  template <class T, class Allocator> class vector; is in a #ifdef block that is only compiled when BOOST_MSVC is defined. Does your program compile with g++ instead of clang++ ?